# How to map sourcetree commit with JIRA

Tags: git, jira, atlassian-sourcetree, git-commit

While creating a commit at sourcetree(I am using gitlab), I am writing commit messages as follows:-

```
MAEFT2-144 Error Handling
```

Note:- MAEFT2-144 is sub task number at JIRA.

But when I see the Git Commits activity at JIRA, then there is no commit shown. How to relate the commit at sourcetree with JIRA?

- Do I need to write a commit message with some specific structure?
- Do I need to perform settings at sourcetree level?
- Do I need to perform settings at JIRA level?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to connect your git repository to Jira for commits to appear on the issues. The first step is giving Jira a permission to access your gitlab account, the second is connecting particular git repository to the Jira project (in your case MAEFT2 project). For detailed instructions of how to connect Jira to a git repository ([see this guide from Atlassian](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver072/linking-a-bitbucket-or-github-repository-with-jira-828787604.html)). 
For a commit to be correlated with an issue, it's enough to include issue key in the commit message as you did.